# Closed and open orbit of electrons

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

What is exactly the difference between closed and open electron orbits?. Is it that, when crossed electric and magnetic field is applied, the electron in the real space does not complete an orbit, and instead follows a helix like path. And only in presence of magnetic field, its orbit is closed? I am unable to get a clear picture of this concept. And how is this related to electron-like and hole-like orbits?. Many of the text-book infer that, if all the states are occupied and electron is orbiting around it, then it is an electron-like, where as, when an electron is orbiting around unoccupied states, it is hole-like. Please help. I am unable to get a clear picture of how all these happens at the fermi-surface. Provide me references, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure that I understand your question. Since I cannot comment, I will give a try at an answer. 
Is it possible that you are mixing up orbitals and orbits? An orbit is the elliptic path of an object around another object, e.g. a planet around a star. An atomic orbital on the other hand is the mathematical description of an electron in an atom. The atomic orbitals form so-called shells (Sommerfeld Atomic model), where people like to imagine electrons orbiting around the atomic nucleus.

Shells can only take up a certain number of electrons. When this number is reached, the shell is closed, otherwise it is open. Maybe this is what you mean with your question... Open shells are reactive while closed shells are rather not. This is why e.g. noble gases are not very reactive... [More on the topic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_shell)

The topics of electrons and holes on the other hand are more related to solid-state physics. But I find it difficult to relate it directly to your question. You could maybe clarify it...

Comment: i am asking about electron and hole orbit, not orbitals. You didnt get my question at all.Anyway, thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

I think by closed and open orbits the author means whether the particle orbits or the energy bands they reside on (in reciprocal space) are contained in a particular Brillouin zone. From semiclassical equations of motion, one can calculate a trajectories (k(t) and r(t)) given a particular dispersion relation ($\epsilon(k)$), and these are the orbits the authors are referring to. For example, when you look at more than one BZ you may have the constant energy contour from one reciprocal cell connected to that of an adjacent cell like in the following picture (From Ashcroft and Mermin's Solid State Physics).

[image: Open orbit indicated by the arrowed curve. Source: Ashcroft & Mermin]